# Loop counts only the first and last three elements (heat conductivity of plate)

Tags: python

I have written a code for heat conductivity of plate. The loop works very strangely counting only the first and last three elements. Can anyone help me?

```
timend = 8
H = 0.10
n, m = 100, 100
h = H / (n-1)
tau = timend / m
t0, th, ts = 550, 700, 350
rho, c, lam = 8800, 381, 384
x = [[350 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]


x[0][0] = t0
x[0][n-1] = th
for i in range(1, m):
    x[i][0], x[i][n-1] = t0, th
    for j in range(1, n-1):
        x[i][j] = x[i][j] + tau * lam / rho / c * (x[i-1][j+1] - 2 * x[i-1][j] + x[i-1][j-1])

print(x[m-1])
```

Comment: Please provide debugging details

Comment: for all other indexes `tau * lam / rho / c * (x[i-1][j+1] - 2 * x[i-1][j] + x[i-1][j-1])` is coming 0.0

Comment: @tard but how? I filled them with the initial value 350

Comment: `tau * lam / rho / c * (x[i-1][j+1] - 2 * x[i-1][j] + x[i-1][j-1])` is equivalent to `(tau * lam * (x[i-1][j+1] - 2 * x[i-1][j] + x[i-1][j-1])) / (rho * c)` -- is this as intended?

Comment: Where are `h` and `H` supposed to be used? I don't see them used after assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm interested to learn about this problem and understand what you're trying to implement!

#### TL;DR - check your formula inside your nested loop.

---

Check your code again, and manually step through code inside your loop once or twice, using your numbers:

Given

```
tau = 0.08
lam = 384
rho = 8800
c = 381
```

then your code says that

```
x[i][j] = x[i][j] + tau * lam / rho / c * (x[i-1][j+1] - 2 * x[i-1][j] + x[i-1][j-1])
```

which we can equivalently rearrange for simplicity as

```
x[i][j] = x[i][j] + (tau / rho) * (lam / c) * (quantity)
```

where `quantity` is `(x[i-1][j-1] + x[i-1][j+1] - 2*x[i-1][j])`. We can plug in our numbers:

```
x[i][j] = x[i][j] + (9.09e-6) * (1.008) * (quantity)
```

If you think about it, when most of your values in the 2D array are `350`, and you're adding `9.6125e-6 * (a quantity approximately 0 in most cases)`, most of your values will remain (to the precision of a `float`-type variable) at `350`.